# database sqlite couldnt run,

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using this simple code to create a table User in my database.

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

   String create_t_user = 
                   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user ("+
                   "ID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
                   "username varchar(20) NOT NULL,"+
                   "password varchar(20) NOT NULL,"+
                   "connected binary(1) NOT NULL,"+
                   "PRIMARY KEY (ID));";
   db.execSQL(create_t_user);
   // ...
```

The logcat shows me an error when I try to run that code. It says

> "04-28 02:49:57.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10649):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax
>   error: CREATE TABLE user (ID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,username
>   varchar(20) NOT NULL,password varchar(20) NOT NULL,connected binary(1)
>   NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (ID))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for a rowid column specification using the autoincrement algorithm for generating rowids is

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Note that `PRIMARY KEY` also implies `NOT NULL`.

So, change the table creation to

```
String create_t_user = 
       "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user ("+
               "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
               "username varchar(20) NOT NULL,"+
               "password varchar(20) NOT NULL,"+
               "connected binary(1) NOT NULL);";
```

Answer (score 0):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` should be `AUTOINCREMENT`